# Action listner not working on image in android with draglayout

Tags: java, android, slide, android-drawable

My xml code :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.my_slide_menu"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="18" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.my_slide_menu.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

And java file

```
    package com.example.my_slide_menu;

    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MotionEvent;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.view.View.OnTouchListener;
    import android.widget.ImageView;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.content.res.Configuration;
    import android.graphics.Color;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
    import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction;
    import android.support.v4.view.GravityCompat;
    import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
    import android.widget.ListView;

    import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;
    import com.actionbarsherlock.view.MenuItem;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {

        private DrawerLayout drawlayout = null;
        ImageView arrow;

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

            System.out.println("On create");

            // drawlayout=(DrawerLayout)findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
            arrow = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.arrow);

    //      getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    //      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    //      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
    //      getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(true);

            arrow.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    System.out.println("Touch");
                    return false;

                }
            });

        }

    }
```

How solve this Proplem.
I want when click on image slider open.But action listner not work on image.
Without drwer click listner working.
I am making a slider menu like face book.
Please help me

My layout file is

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/arrow"
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:src="@drawable/a" />

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/content_frame"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listview_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start"
            android:background="#111"
            android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
            android:divider="@android:color/transparent"
            android:dividerHeight="0dp" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Where is this image in view ?

Answer (score 0):

Set **arrow** as ImageButton or add:

```
android:clickable="true" android:focusable="true"
```

Hope it helps